# How to use the plugins within the vendor folder instead of the gems in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a scenario where I need to modify certain functions within my plugin. So I thought I can change the files within the `vendor/plugins/` folder. But then I realized that my installed gems code has been used by rails instead of `vendor/plugins/`. I thought of removing the gem from my `gemlist` but that throws an error. So how can I redirect my rails to use the plugins within `vendor/plugins/` folder instead of my gems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try, per the [bundler doc](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html):

```
gem [gem name], :path => [path]
```

Ex:

```
gem "rails", :path => "vendor/rails"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try monkey patching instead of modifying plugins/gems directly.  I monkey patch them in the lib/ folder and config.auto_load it in my environment.  It's not too bad, just make sure it's in the same modules, and has the same method name.  For instance, to override a string method, you could do something like:

```
class String
  def method_to_override
    do_something
    super # if you want to still use the original method
  end
end
```

I recommend trying to stay away from directly modifying anything directly.

Also, if I'm using bundled gems, I usually bundle exec command, but I think that still loads the gems out of the path I chose.  I have rarely used plugins as of late.